# How to check if AVPlayer has Video or just Audio?

Tags: xcode, audio, video, avplayer

I try to play some "media" but at the time the AVPlayer starts I don't know if it is audio or Video.

I connected the player Layer and it works fine.

```
self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[[PCPlayerManager sharedManager] audioPlayer]];
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoView.frame.size.width, videoView.frame.size.height);
[videoView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
```

But how can I check if there is Video so I can add/remove some Options?

Answer (score 12):

From Apple’s sample code project AVSimplePlayer:

```
// Set up an AVPlayerLayer according to whether the asset contains video.
if ([[(AVAsset *)asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] != 0)
```

Comment: That's not working for me ; I'm reading both video &  audio streams and the count is always 0

Comment: I this doesn't work for you maybe you're doing it too early. Wait until your player item status becomes readyToPlay.

Comment: What if the video has an audio track and has no sound, how can i detect this?

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 4.2 you can do the following:

```
func isAudioAvailable() -> Bool? {
   return self.player?._asset?.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == AVMediaType.audio}).count != 0   
}

func isVideoAvailable() -> Bool? {
   return self.player?._asset?.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == AVMediaType.video}).count != 0   
}
```

or as extension

```
extension AVPlayer {
    var isAudioAvailable: Bool? {
        return self._asset?.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == AVMediaType.audio}).count != 0
    }

    var isVideoAvailable: Bool? {
        return self._asset?.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == AVMediaType.video}).count != 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Value of type 'AVPlayer' has no member '_asset' :(

Comment: just replace _asset with asset

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but `AVPlayerItem` has the following array `[mPlayerItem.asset.tracks]` This contains two objects,one for video and another for audio.Access it as follows `[mPlayerItem.asset.tracks objectAtIndex:0]` for video and `[mPlayerItem.asset.tracks objectAtIndex:1]` for audio.

Comment: What if the video has an audio track and has no sound, how can i detect this?

Comment: Have you tried checking something like isPlayable, isDecodable or totalSampleDataLength of the AVAssetTrack? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but just tried it and there is no difference in the values!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
    // source from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581216 Changed for last release AVFoundation
    func isAudioAvailable() -> Bool? {
        return self.player.currentItem?.tracks.filter({$0.assetTrack!.mediaType == AVMediaType.audio}).count != 0
    }
    
    func isVideoAvailable() -> Bool? {
        return self.player.currentItem?.tracks.filter({$0.assetTrack!.mediaType == AVMediaType.video}).count != 0
    }
```

Comment: You're doing the same in both functions :) Are you sure that's intentional?

Answer (score 0):

I found this better solution

```
func isVideoAvailable(item: AVPlayerItem) -> Bool {
        for video in item.tracks {
            if video.assetTrack?.mediaType == .video {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
}
```

And this

```
  if currentItem.tracks.contains(where: { track in
     track.assetTrack?.mediaType == .video
  }) {

     // This Code goes Here!
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** sean-stayns answer in Swift 5.5

```
extension AVPlayer {
    var isAudioAvailable: Bool? {
        return self.currentItem?.asset.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == .audio}).count != 0
    }

    var isVideoAvailable: Bool? {
        return self.currentItem?.asset.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == .video}).count != 0
    }
}
```