# How to check the existence of an audio stream in the player. AVPlayer, swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer

I use AVPlayer to play video in my project, and now I need to check if there is an audio stream or not.

```
playerController.player?.currentItem?.asset.tracks
```

is empty when I check it.
How can i check it?

Comment: Check for count, if count is 1 only video, if count is 2 audio also will be there. Check for "playerController.player?.currentItem?.asset.tracks[1]" value.

Comment: I did. Count = 0.
if i try to get tracks[0] or tracks[1] i catch an exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if AVPlayer has Video or just Audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704322/how-to-check-if-avplayer-has-video-or-just-audio)