# UICollectionView gets stuck while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avplayer

I have a few videos in my `collectionView` cell. I am fetching them from an URL and playing it using `AVPlayer`.

**Everything works fine**. But, there is a requirement to show a mute/unmute icon depending on if the video contains audio or not.

In order to check if the video contains audio or not I used this code:

```
(self.player?.currentItem?.asset.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == AVMediaType.audio}).count != 0)
```

I got this from: [How to check if AVPlayer has Video or just Audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704322/how-to-check-if-avplayer-has-video-or-just-audio)

**As soon as I add this code my collectionView stuck for the very first time when I scroll the collection view.**

I am calling it from cell's **init**.
Tried performing it on background thread but still, I am getting the issue.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let isAudioAvailable = (self.player?.currentItem?.asset.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == AVMediaType.audio}).count != 0)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.audioIconButton.isHidden = !isAudioAvailable
        self.player?.isMuted = isMuted
        let image = isMuted ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Mute_Icon") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Unmute_Icon")
        self.audioIconButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    })
}
```

Code to fetch from URL:

```
func getAVPlayerFromUrl(view: UIView) -> AVPlayer? {
    let size: CGSize = view.bounds.size.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: UIScreen.main.scale, y: UIScreen.main.scale))
    guard let url = URL(string: AppConfig.shared.appConfig.video_buckets.videoURL(for: self, size: size)) else { return nil }

    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    videoAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["playable"])
    let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoAsset)
    return AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}
```

Please let me know what's going wrong here.
Or Is there any other way to distinguish if a video contains audio or not?

Comment: Instead of checking the player's current item, can you check your data source for this data?

Comment: @CerlinBoss can you please let me know how to do? FYI I fetch this video from the URL and play it in AVPlayer.

Comment: Can you add the fetch logic to the question?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Try adding a completionHandler to `loadValuesAsynchronously` and get the count and cache it. Later inside init, check the cached value

Comment: Thanks! Will try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It worked me for thanks!.
@CerlinBoss I request you add it as an answer it may help others,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to cache the count on loading the `asset` instead of loading the `cell`

So the fetch logic will change to something similar to below code

```
func getAVPlayerFromUrl(view: UIView, cellIndex: Int) -> AVPlayer? {
    let size: CGSize = view.bounds.size.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: UIScreen.main.scale, y: UIScreen.main.scale))
    guard let url = URL(string: AppConfig.shared.appConfig.video_buckets.videoURL(for: self, size: size)) else { return nil }

    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    videoAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["playable"]) {
        // Here audioCount is the dict we are using to save the count and cellIndex is the index of the cell in collectionview
        self.audioCount[cellIndex] = videoAsset.tracks.filter({$0.mediaType == AVMediaType.audio}).count
    }
    let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoAsset)
    return AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}
```

And finally use it like

```
let isAudioAvailable = (self.audioCount[index] != 0)
self.audioIconButton.isHidden = !isAudioAvailable
self.player?.isMuted = isMuted
let image = isMuted ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Mute_Icon") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Unmute_Icon")
self.audioIconButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```